# What are the Control-key combinations/chords?

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode

Because of Vim's modes, there is not a lot of holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while pressing another key. However ,in insert (or replace) mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> will let you paste a register, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> lets you insert any character literally. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> deletes a word, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> backspaces a letter.

What's the term for these key sequences?

Are there more of them?

Comment: Maybe not an official term, but I've heard the word *chord* used to describe key sequences with `Ctrl`.

Comment: Drew Neil uses the term *chord* in his book *Practical Vim*. (I'm not saying that he is the first to use the term, but I think that's where I first saw it.)

Answer (score 7):

The [insert.txt Vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html) calls these "special keys", and the docs can be brought up with [`:help ins-special-keys`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-special-keys). Some fun examples:

- adjust the indentation of the line you're currently typing with <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> lets you insert [digraphs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraphs) (e.g. <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> inserts a "✓")
- when you're ready to get out of insert mode, save your left wrist some movement by using <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> instead of <kbd>Escape</kbd>

There are also some "special special keys", docs are at [`:help ins-special-special`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-special-special).